# Capture multiple variables

Tags: powershell, variables, input, inputbox

I currently have a powershell script that allows me to enter in the details for users one at a time which can then be used as variables later on. At present the script calls for each input and then saves for as a variable, this is then repeated 10 times.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$NameOne = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter UserName")
$firstname,$surname = $NameOne -split("\.")
$NameTwo = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter UserName")
$firstname,$surname = $NameTwo -split("\.")
```

Is there a way to shorten the script to both allow usernames to be input and stored but to also move on to the next part of the script when an InputBox has no data input?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
$Users = while(($Username = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter UserName")).Trim() -ne "")
{
    $firstname,$surname = $Username -split '\.'
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Firstname = $firstname
        Surname   = $surname
        Username  = $Username
    }
}
```

When the user inputs nothing or whitespace, the loop will exit, otherwise it'll create a new "User object" that will end up in the `$Users` array

Comment: Brilliant, Thank You.